# How can I make model unlearn? reverse backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, backpropagation

I stumbled upon a highly dimensional **minimum** that I can't seem to reproduce no matter how many hundreds of models I train.

The problem is that I went a few epochs too far and *overfit* on the training data. My early stopping criteria was too ambitious so I never hit it.

How can I retrain the model to perform *worse* on the training data? I've tried:

- Combinations of higher learning rates and momentums to force exploration in the loss space
- Using different batch sizes
- Different optimizers

[image]

Comment: If you want your model to unlearn, i.e. have a higher loss on the training data, you can try applying gradient ascent instead of gradient descent.

Comment: ooo yeah like multiplying loss by `-1`

Comment: Never heard of gradient ascent, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Add a small amount of random noise to the weights/biases.  I’d  multiply each weight/bias $i$ by $(1 + \epsilon \cdot R_i)$, where $R_i$ is a zero-centered random number, and $\epsilon$ controls the relative amount of noise added.  Set $\epsilon$ small the first time you try this (maybe $|\epsilon \cdot R_i| \sim .01$).  Then try retraining.  If it finds a better solution, great; otherwise repeat with a larger $\epsilon$.  This is basically just simulated annealing.